# Why is my solution wrong? (Putnam 1985 B2)

Tags: calculus

Define polynomials $f_n (x)$ for $n ≥ 0$ by $f_0 (x) = 1$, $f_n (0) = 0$ for $n ≥ 1$, and
$\frac{d}{dx}
(f _{n+1} (x)) = (n + 1)f_n (x + 1)
dx$
for $n ≥ 0$. Find, with proof, the explicit factorization of $f_{100} (1)$ into powers
of distinct primes.

My proof:

Rewrite the recursive equation as $
f _{n} (x) = $

$n \int f_{n-1} (x + 1) dx =$

$n \int (n-1)\int f_{n-2} (x + 2) d(x+1) =$ ...

and put $n= 100$ to get

$f _{100} (x) = 100! \int\int....\int f_0(x+100) d(x+99) = (x+99)^{100}$

and the answer is $100^{100}$.

My answer is wrong - it should be $101^{99}$ and the given solution is different: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol858.html

So why is my solution wrong?

Comment: The problem is with the fact that you have written indefinite integrals when you mean definite integrals.  Once you try to write in the limits of integration you will see that it is not as easy as it seems to do so.  Note that you can replace 100 by 2 and you will already see the problem.

Comment: @HughThomas how are limits of integration relevant to the problem?

Comment: @user1299784 Limits of integration are relevant because of the condition $f_n(0)=0$.  Your solution for $f_{100}$ has $f_{100}(0) = 99^{100}$ so it can't be right.

Comment: As people have said: limits of integration is why. To see the flaw more clearly, instead of writing $f_n = \int \int \ldots dx$ start at the bottom: $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f_n(x) = n!$. This tells you that $f_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading term $x^n$ and no constant term since $f_n(0)=0$. However you don't (yet) know anything about the other terms in $f_n(x) = x^n + A_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + A_1 x$. These are fixed by: $A_k = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^k}f_n(0) = {n\choose k} f_{n-k}(k)$. Thus if you want to use your method you need to find a way to determine the $A_k$'s.

Answer (score 0):

The OP writes:

$$f_n(x) = n \int f_{n-1}(x+1)\, dx $$

The righthand side is an antiderivative, i.e., a whole family of functions, so it doesn't make sense to plug 1 into the RHS.  Thus this equation cannot serve as a formula for $f_n(1)$.

The way that I see to make the OP's equation into something which you can imagine plugging 1 into, is to interpret it as:

$$f_n(x)= n\int_0^x f_{n-1}(t+1)\, dt $$

If we now attempt to iterate, in the way the OP has in mind, we get

$$f_n(x) = n \int_0^x (n-1) \int_0^{t+1} f_{n-2}(u+1)\, du\, dt $$

What we eventually wind up with is

$$f_n(x_0) = n \int_0^{x_0} (n-1) \int_0^{x_1+1} (n-2) \int_0^{x_2+1}\cdots \int_0^{x_{n-1}+1} 1 \,dx_{n}\dots dx_1$$

If you now carry out the integrations sequentially, the result is not obvious (at least to me).  In particular, it doesn't yield the answer the OP claims to have obtained.  (Easy to check for $n=2$.)

Edited to correct the differentials appearing on the RHS of the last formula.